# Active Admin has taken over my routes completely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, activeadmin

im building a basic ecommerce app to teach myself rails, and ive hit a problem.  I had already installed devise and had two user models: 'users' and 'merchants'.  I then installed active_admin and setup it's standard 'admin_user' model.

The admin section works as intended however now the view of every resource that active admin has access to has become the admin version.

Even my root now routes to the active admin login (assuming no one's logged in)

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
devise_for :merchants
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

devise_for :users

resources :products
resources :categories
resources :brands

get "static/about"
get "static/contact"
get "static/cookie"
get "static/faq"
get "static/help"
get "static/index"
get "static/privacy"
get "static/terms"

root :to => 'static#index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which rails parses route priority is from top to bottom so, first created -> highest priority. Active Admin also has a `root :to => 'admin#dashboard` route so your app is trying to load that as the main root route right now.

Try moving `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` below your `root :to => 'static#index'`